# How to use a C# keyword - ref as an identifier in Razor TBB

Tags: 2011, razormediator

My XML name in Schema is `ref` which is a Text field in the Metadata. When I am trying to display this field as

```
@Component.Metadata.ref
```

it throws an error:

> identifier expected, ref is a keyword

as I am trying to use a keyword - ref

I have tried different options, such as:

```
<text> @Component.Metadata.ref </text>
@: @Component.Metadata.ref
@{Component.Metadata.ref;}
```

But still get the same error for each of them.

I tried using one more `@` as in C# we use to skip the keyword name:

```
@Component.Metadata.@@ref
```

But razor then says:

> Argument missing

And with

```
@Component.Metadata.@@ref
```

Razor displays `@ref` instead of ref value

Could someone please suggest how I can display its value?

The Razor version is 1.2.

Comment: What type of field is `ref` in the Schema?

Comment: "ref" is a text field in the Metadata.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
@Package.GetValue("Component.Metadata.ref")
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it but I think this would work

```
@(Component.Metadata.@ref)
```